# Empty /var/log/btmp file - Doesn't fill when a bad login occurs

Tags: ssh, vps, debian-wheezy

I'm on a VPS which runs Debian 7.0 64bits.
And my problem is that all the SSH attempts of connection which failed doesn't appear on my /var/log/btmp file. 
So when I do :

```
sudo lastb
```

It (only) prints me :

```
btmp begins Tue Jul 28 18:32:30 2015
```

Here you got the rights of /var/log/btmp

```
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp 1 Jul  2 21:27 /var/log/btmp
```

And for your information, the /var/log/wtmp is correct and the 'last' command works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a couple of cases in which hacked machines had the attributes modified so the logs can't be written. Please post the output of lsattr /var/log/btmp to make sure it's not immutable.

Comment: thanks for your help !
Here you are :
  -------------e-- /var/log/btmp

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue today on a Centos 7 server.
/var/log/btmp stayed empty after the last log rotation.
Aide (from the eponym package) pointed me in the right direction :

```
File: /var/log/btmp
 SELinux  : system_u:object_r:faillog_t:s0   , system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0
```

Checking:

```
ls -Z /var/log/*tmp*
-rw-------. root utmp system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0   /var/log/btmp
-rw-------. root utmp system_u:object_r:faillog_t:s0   /var/log/btmp-20200501
-rw-rw-r--. root utmp system_u:object_r:wtmp_t:s0      /var/log/wtmp
```

After restorecon, btmp was growing again.

```
restorecon -v /var/log/btmp
restorecon reset /var/log/btmp context system_u:object_r:var_log_t:s0->system_u:object_r:faillog_t:s0
```